Ambient occlusion falloff
I am trying to work with the Ambient Occlusion node in Blender 4.2.0 using Cycles to try and get a nice gradient falloff on my background, however it's creating large triangular shadows in the corners of the room:

Above is the isolated ao with an exaggerated strength to display it properly. Below is what the scene looks like:

I would like to get rid of the small triangle that forms in the corner. I already tried beveling the walls to try and smooth it out slightly, sadly this did not help.
Additionally, here is the shader editor setup I have for the material:


Isn't it natural and expected result of light rays bouncing in reality? Sure the AO is a fake effect to speed up rendering (fake indirect lightning) or use it to fake aging ... so you can't expect 100% realism. So the help here depends on your need - realism or fake even gradients from edges?
